# Unable to Choose another Option in Select tags. Always defaults to first option with a value

Tags: javascript, html

There are similar questions like this, but I either can't find what I am looking for, or I may be missing something. Here is the code below.

```
        <select id="colorSelector" onchange="getColor()">
        <option>Choose a color</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        </select>
```

JS

```
function getColor(){
if(document.getElementById('colorSelector').value = "green"){
    document.getElementById('mainButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'colorChangeGreen()')

}else if(document.getElementById('colorSelector').value = "red"){
    document.getElementById('mainButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'colorChangeRed()')
}}
```

After I open dropdown and choose either of the two colors, it always chooses green and then I can't choose red. I am wondering what I need to edit to be able to choose other colors, I wanted to put a few more options in.
Thank you

Comment: `=` is **assignment**. `==` and `===` are equality checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <select id="colorSelector" onchange="getColor()">
    <option>Choose a color</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="mainButton" value="color" />  


<script>
function getColor(){
if(document.getElementById('colorSelector').value == "green"){
    document.getElementById('mainButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'colorChangeGreen()')

}else if(document.getElementById('colorSelector').value == "red"){
    document.getElementById('mainButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'colorChangeRed()')
}}
</script>
```

Comment: when ever you use if condition you should use comparison operators instead of assignments operators

Comment: Yes, thank you. something I won't forget now.